# PHP Input Output is stuck?

Tags: php, echo

```php
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass") or 
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("smcs"); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM others");  
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0]; 
?>
```

Each time I echo anything it shows number `1`.

I don't know if there is a `1` stuck from other file in the input stream?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't use Super User for programming questions. Your question will automatically be migrated to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), our sister site for developers...

Comment: How to show the whole row?? assume I have three column "id" "author" "topic".

Comment: Enumerate over `$row` with a for loop, so you get `$row[1]`, `$row[2]` and so on. You might also be interested in [the end of the example here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) for a better approach. I've posted a whole answer below...

Comment: Make sure to check the `mysql_fetch_assoc` together with `extract($row)`, it makes it a lot easier. :)

Answer (score 1):

`1` is the first value from the first row from your table.

**Hint:** Identity column.

---

Don't use `*` in queries, you'll end up selecting more data than you'll want, which is slower.

---

If you want to get all the values, enumerate over `$row` with a for loop.

You might also be interested in [the end of the example here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) for a better approach:

```php
// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus so you don't need $row.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}

// Make sure that we be nice to our valuable memory.
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: the code above is just to test but what I really want to do is to view  each entry in the table from the db and put on table on webpage and put beside each row a radio bottom to modify the row. I'm in progress if you have any info that could help. I intend to build simlp cms

Comment: @lman25: Feel free to ping me on chat (type @Tom) in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access.